# React-dom.js import statement results in Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined.

Tags: reactjs

I am writing test component for integration into my project using Typescript and react in Visual Studio. I could use some help tracking down why the following code has an issue:

`define(["require", "exports", 'react', 'react-dom'], function (require, exports, React, ReactDo`m)

On the Scripts/typings/react-dom/react-dom.d.ts reference path line, an error is flagged stating:
**"Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined"**
The line the error is reported on is Line 8, col 1 of the javascript version shown below:

The typescript component looks like this:

```
///<reference path='../../Scripts/typings/react/react.d.ts' />
///<reference path='../../Scripts/typings/react-dom/react-dom.d.ts' />

import React = require('react');
import ReactDom = require('react-dom');


interface P {
name?: string;
}

interface S {
complete?: boolean;
}


class Goal extends React.Component<P, S> {
state: S = {
    complete: false
}

private _toggleCompletion = () => {
    this.setState({ complete: !this.state.complete });
}

render() {
    var status = 'Status: ' + (this.state.complete ? 'complete' : 'incomplete');
    return React.DOM.div({
        children: [
            React.DOM.div({}, this.props.name + ' - ' + status),
            React.DOM.button({
                onClick: this._toggleCompletion
            }, 'Toggle completion')
        ]
    });
}
}

ReactDom.render(React.createElement(Goal, { name: 'Learn React and TypeScript' }),
    document.getElementById('react'));
```

The compiled Javscript version of this file is as follows:

```
 /// <reference path='../../Scripts/typings/react/react.d.ts' />
    /// <reference path='../../Scripts/typings/react-dom/react-dom.d.ts' />
    var __extends = (this && this.__extends) || function (d, b) {
    for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p];
    function __() { this.constructor = d; }
    d.prototype = b === null ? Object.create(b) : (__.prototype = b.prototype, new __());
};
define(["require", "exports", 'react', 'react-dom'], function (require, exports, React, ReactDom) {
    var Goal = (function (_super) {
        __extends(Goal, _super);
        function Goal() {
            var _this = this;
            _super.apply(this, arguments);
            this.state = {
                complete: false
            };
            this._toggleCompletion = function () {
                _this.setState({ complete: !_this.state.complete });
            };
        }
        Goal.prototype.render = function () {
            var status = 'Status: ' + (this.state.complete ? 'complete' : 'incomplete');
            return React.DOM.div({
                children: [
                    React.DOM.div({}, this.props.name + ' - ' + status),
                    React.DOM.button({
                        onClick: this._toggleCompletion
                    }, 'Toggle completion')
                ]
            });
        };
        return Goal;
    })(React.Component);
    ReactDom.render(React.createElement(Goal, { name: 'Learn React and TypeScript' }), document.getElementById('react'));
});
```

Comment: Looks like you're having problem with **define** function, which is obviously not defined in scope where called.

Comment: This was a module loader issue.  I am not using modules as the moment but my Visual Studio project has AMD --module flag enabled.  Therefore it was looking for a define function in scope and I didn't have one when using require() with React.js.  For now I turned off module support and removed require statements to just rely on reference paths to d.ts files.  All works now.    Thanks for chiming in.